# How to extract string from string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

how to store Height Value separately "6ft 7inch"
6ft in one string and 7inch in another string.

6 and 7 will be dynamically changes ft inch will be constant.

Comment: Why is this Q marked with *unclear, what you're asking*?

Answer (score 2):

I assume there will always be a single space character separating the 2 height values that you want to extract. You can use -componentsSeparatedByString method to turn the string into array of strings separated by the space character

```
NSString *originalString = @"6ft 7inch";
NSArray *separatedStrings = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSString *feetString = separatedStrings[0];
NSString *inchString = separatedStrings[1];
```

If there could be cases where there are no spaces in between you'll have to find the index of the key character set and then create substrings using them. Let me know if you need to know how

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split the string.

```
NSString *combineString=@"6ft 7inch";
NSArray *stringsArray=[combineString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

if ([stringsArray count ]> 0) {

    //here is the ft string
    NSString *ftString=[stringsArray objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([stringsArray count ]> 1)
    {
        //here is the inch string
        NSString *inchString=[stringsArray objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Inch value not found");
    }

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Empty String");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to accomplish that. However, in your case it is the easiest way, so separate the string at the space:

```
NSString *string = @"6ft 7inch";
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
```